# Why does booting in debian freeze at /dev/sda1: clean

Tags: debian, kernel

I need a new debian kernel to activate a module available only on version 5.13 and more. So I found a tutorial to configure, build and install it.

After rebooting the computer and selecting through grub the new kernel, the computer get stuck at `/dev/sda1: clean`.
Booting on the new kernel in recovery mode don't avoid the problem.

I can ping and ssh into the computer when the main terminal is frozen, and the new kernel is runing :

```
debian@debian:~$ uname -r
5.13.7
```

I already tried `fsck -f /dev/sda1` from a live ubuntu but there is no error for the disk.

Do you know how to correct the problem ? I don't want to have an ethernet interface dedicated to ssh because I need them all to try the new module.

PS : I didn't installed a graphical interface for the OS

Edit :

- `find /usr/lib/modules/5.13.7/kernel/drivers/ nvidia` doesn't find anything
- For the console driver I don't know where to find it, `cat /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind` return `1` (I have only vtcon1)
- `systemctl status` return `State : running`
- `cat /proc/fb` return nothing

Comment: No console driver, perhaps? Did you perhaps install the nVidia drivers (because that would blacklist the "noveau" module that would normally provide the console on nV cards?

Comment: The fact that you can ping and ssh into the computer indicates the system in fact comes up into multi-user mode. Run `systemctl status`: if the second line says `State: degraded`, run `systemctl` without any options and see which services in the displayed list have failed. Also please run `cat /proc/fb` and edit your question to tell us what it says.

Comment: My expectation is that there is no console driver, so systemd does not generate getty invocations, so none of the zero getty invocations are missing, hence the system is not "degraded."

Comment: @SimonRichter I researched how to install the console driver but I couldn't find anything. Do you have an idea or a link on how to do it ? Maybe a graphic interface can bypass the problem, I will look for that at the same time.